# animationEasing proper syntax

Tags: jquery, syntax, slider, jquery-animate, easing

I'm using a jquery slider from: http://pioul.fr/jquery-diyslider

on it his example shows params set as:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "400px", // width of the slider
    height: "200px", // height of the slider
    display: 3, // number of slides you want it to display at once
    loop: false, // disable looping on slides
    animationDuration: 300
});
```

he says you can add Easing with "animationEasing", so i modified the example with:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "400px", // width of the slider
    height: "200px", // height of the slider
    display: 3, // number of slides you want it to display at once
    loop: false, // disable looping on slides
    animationDuration: 300,
    animationEasing: 'easeOutCubic'
});
```

but it doesn't ease. I also tried other easing options on https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html to no avail. Am i missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Have you imported jquery ui?

Comment: yes, the script is working fine, just not the easing. he doesn't have an example syntax for using animationEasing so i'm not sure how to add it.

Comment: but for this slider you need only jQuery (thats a dependency of the slider) and it allows you to use `'swing'` and `'linear'` as a parameter. For more easing options, you need to include also `jquery ui`. You already have it on your project?

Comment: oh, i see. i didn't realize that. well, i added jquery ui but it still doesn't ease. even 'swing' doesn't work which makes me think i'm not coding it right. it's defaulting to linear.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: here's one someone else did: http://jsfiddle.net/bj4yZ/155/. i just copy/pasted the frame source and tried adding animationEasing: 'swing' but it still defaults to linear.

Comment: I added jquery mobile and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj4yZ/905/) and its working fine? I tested on chrome and safari.

Comment: hmm, ok. thanks for verifying that the code was right. i'll see what else is causing it not to work for me, esp that my libs are loading properly. thanks again.